# Error: Expected a ')'?

Tags: c++, constants

I am trying to use a Constant named SENT to be the stopping point for my program. but I am getting an error on my SENT constant that it is expecting a ')', but I do not see where this ')' should go or even why it needs it.  This error happens every time I use my Constant SENT, which is 2 times.  Can someone please help me figure out why I am getting this error?  I have to do my program this way, so please don't suggest other implementations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

#define SENT 4;

int main(void)
{
int r1,r2, c;

do
{
displayMenu();
c = getMenuChoice();
gen2Rand(r1,r2);
drillOneProb(c,r1,r2);
cout << endl << endl;
}while(c!=SENT); //ERROR:EXPTECTED A ')' on SENT. FIRST OCCURENCE HERE. 
return 0;
}
```

-------------------- 2nd occurence

```
while(valid==false)
{
cout << "Enter the number of the operation to try (1-4)" << endl;
cin >> c;
cout << endl;
if(c<1||c>SENT) //ERROR: EXPECTED A ')' on SENT. 2ND OCCURRENCE HERE.
{
    cout << "(BEEP) Input value is out of range." << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try : `#define SENT 4` without the semicolon at the end of it

Comment: I will, waiting for the timer.

Answer (score 7):

When `SENT` is replaced by `4;` the semi-colon terminates the while loop without a closing `)`.

You want `#define SENT 4` - no semi-colon.